# Set offset of jquery position from right of window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

I have a popup element that appears upon clicking a menu element, and I'd like it to be positioned relative to the right side of the window instead of the left. So far, this works for finding the left offset value:

```
$(window).load(function(){    
                $("li.account").click(function(event) {
                $(".popup_menu").toggleClass("show");
                //Get
                    var p = $("li.account");
                    var offset = p.offset();

                //set
                    $(".popup_menu").offset({
                        top: offset.top + 25,
                        left: offset.left - 60})
            });
```

But I'm having trouble working out how to position it from the right (so I can have the window re-sized by the user and it maintains it's relative position to the parent element).

Comment: It seems like you would be better off having this logic within CSS and just triggering a class change on click.

Comment: Really? I was under the impression it required a checkbox hack to provide a show/hide element with CSS. How would you reccomend I rewrite this?